# Android XML parsing AsyncTask

Tags: android, xml, android-asynctask

I have a problem with parsing XML from URL. Im creating a weather app and i want to parse xml from http://api.openweathermap.org/ . I use for this AsyncTask and it's not working. Here is my code and thanks for any replies. Only ProgressDialog is showing and no more. Also i have internet permission in manifest.

Weather.java

```
public class Weather extends AsyncTask<String[],Void,String[]> {

private MainActivity activity;
private XmlPullParserFactory factoryObj;
private String url;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;


public Weather(MainActivity activity, String url) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.url = url;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.setTitle("Please wait");
    pDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected String[] doInBackground(String[]... params) {

    try{

        URL myurl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) myurl.openConnection();
        connection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();


        factoryObj = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        XmlPullParser parser = factoryObj.newPullParser();

        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES,false);
        parser.setInput(stream,null);
        String[] result = parseXML(parser);
        stream.close();
        return result;
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public String[] parseXML(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException,XmlPullParserException{


    int event;
    String text=null;
    String[] result =new String[1];


    event = parser.getEventType();

    while(event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
        String name = parser.getName();

        switch(event){

            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                if(name.equals("temperature"))
                    result[0] = parser.getAttributeValue(null,"value");
                break;

        }
        parser.next();


    }

    return result;
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    pDialog.dismiss();
    activity.callBackData(result);
}
}
```

and MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


TextView temp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    temp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temptextView);


    String url ="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=warsaw&mode=xml&appid=35fae97674d2f8032b66a35addf05450";
    new Weather(this,url).execute();

}


public void callBackData(String[] result) {
    temp.setText(result[0]);

}
}
```

Comment: is this throwing an exception?

Comment: No, aplication never stops.

Answer (score 0):

Please move the code from END_TAG to START_TAG

```
case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
    if(name.equals("temperature"))
         result[0] = parser.getAttributeValue(null,"value");
     break;
```

this is because the "temperature" does not have an explicit ending tag

Comment: this is a XML file,  i think ening tag is explict

here is piece of code from xml:

      <temperature value="292.08" min="289.82" max="295.93"  unit="kelvin"/>
<humidity value="64" unit="%"/>
<pressure value="3" unit="hPa"/>

Comment: Explicit in the sense that it doesn't have </temperature>. Anyhow, does my suggestion works?

Comment: <country>PL</country>

     if(name.equals("country"))
                        result[0] = parser.getText();

Doesnt work :(

Comment: any ideas  how can i get value from <temperature ... /> tag?

Comment: @Mateusz if this answers your questions, please consider to accept it

Answer (score 0):

@Lino you were right! I change END_TAG to START_TAG and everything is ok! Thank you